# sequence diagram for android application that uses NFC

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

The below diagram is based on an android application. When the application loads the user is given 3 button to select add, update and Search. On click on add button the user is given an option to add a new user or add a new item. When the user selects the add item option he enters the required data. Once the data is entered the system check if all the values are entered is correct. if it is correct it is saved if not the user is asked to re-enter the values.One the data is saved the user is asked to write the asset id to an NFC tag.

The same process is applied for update section.

In the search the user is given 2 option to either search the asset through text or by tapping the NFC device onto the NFC tag to search the desired item from the database.

I wanted to know if the sequence diagram I have done is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `Choose an Option` messages. The machine does not trigger anything at the actor. It's the actor who decides. So the initial message always comes from the actor.

The `Return Result` is implicit with the dotted line. Instead describe **what** is being returned.

Finally (and most important) you do not use objects but classes in your SD. Always (!) use objects since its an object which communicates, not a class.